# Apex:SelectRadio Have no default option selected

Tags: visualforce, selectoption, selectradio

For Apex:SelectRadio components do they always have a default value selected when first rendered on the visualforce page and when the selectOptions are specified directly in the visualforce page as opposed to from a list binded from the Controller?

For the following code "No" is selected as default when the page loads.  I do not want a default option selected. Any help on how i can achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!triedToReturnCall}" id="returnedCall" layout="pageDirection" borderVisible="false" required="true">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="true" itemLabel="Yes"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="false" itemLabel="No"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FRed:

The doc states that `SelectOption` class is created as:

```
public SelectOption(String value, String label)
```

Hence, the value bound to the controller property `triedToReturnCall` will be a string. If you default (in the controller) `triedToReturnCall` to null, no radio button is default selected. Otherwise, SFDC looks for a match between the `itemValue` of the `apex:selectOption` and the value of `triedToReturnCall` to default the radio.